# how to see php errors returned in a cron job

Tags: php, cron

I've got a script that PIPES an email address but it's not doing what I need it to do and I believe it's returning some php FATAL errors.  I have it setup to log some responses already and write the responses to a .html file however how do I get the FATAL errors to log in that same .html file so I can debug my script?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the cron command to something like

```
php myJob.php >> stdout.log 2>> stderr.log
```

This should redirect the regular output to `stdout.log` and the errors to `stderr.log`.

Comment: K actually I am wrong...I have changed my question..it's not a cron job it's a PIPE command...

Comment: I am going to accept your answer because it was correct based on the title and original question I asked...my bad for not asking the quetion correctly :)